# Creating elements through a for loop in js

Tags: javascript, for-loop, element, p5.js

I'm trying to create a virtual piano site, and i need to make the keys separate elements as I'm creating them with this loop;

```
function draw() {
    background(220);
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 59; i++) {
        //constructs the white keys
        
        fill(255);
        rect(i * 10, 350, 10, 50);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 58; i++) {
        //skips keys for black keys using 7 note repetition pattern
        if (i % 7 == 0 || i % 7 == 2 || i % 7 == 3 || i % 7 == 5 || i % 7 == 6) {
            fill(0);
            rect(i * 10 + 7.5, 350, 5, 30);
        }
    }
}
```

how could i save the different keys as different elements to merge them with the sound files with document.querySelectorAll('key name'). As it is my first question here, I'm not sure the format is correct, but i really really need help. thank you.

Comment: What are those `background`, `fill` and `rect` functions you're calling? Are you painting on a canvas?

Comment: Yes. they are p5 functions

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating an object class of a key, then create an array of objects and draw them. In that way, you can quite easily get a reference value to the key you want to add a particular sound to.

Create two arrays, one for the objects and the other for the sound files. You may use the mousePressed() function along with constraints to check it's location on the canvas (by adding a function inside the object class) and then assign a value from the sound array according to the position of the respective keys.

You can learn more about what I've said by watching this P5.js tutorial playlist by The Coding Train (Daniel Shiffman): https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Zy51Q-x9tMWIv9cueOFTFA